# Use of split function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting CSS 'left' property value. now it is set on -50. so i want to get only 50 can this be done with split function or there is another way to do that. Also why split function is not working in my function

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.box').click(function (){

    var kar=parseInt($(this).css('left'))

var jj= kar.split('')

alert(jj[0])

    })

});
</script>


<style>

.container {

    margin:auto;
    width:500px;
    position:relative

}


.box { background:#FF0000; width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute;left:-50px;}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [Math.abs function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
Math.abs(-50); // 50
Math.abs("-50"); // 50
```

The [split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) works on strings and returns an array with all parts of the string separated by the given delimiter. You are giving an empty string as delimiter, which splits your string after each character like this:

```
"-50".split(""); // result is: ["-","5","0"]
var kar = -50;
kar.split(""); // TypeError: kar.split is not a function
```

If you are getting a string back like `"-50px"`, then you can do it like this:

```
var leftAsInt = parseInt("-50px".replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, ""),10);
console.log(Math.abs(leftAsInt)); // 50
```

Also: there is no jQuery involved in this (besides the `.css()` function), `split` and `abs` are functions of [JavaScript's predefined core objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects) `String` and `Math`.

Answer (score 1):

use Math.abs:

```
var kar = parseInt($(this).css('left')),
    jj = Math.abs(kar);
```

References:

- [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

Answer (score 1):

how about trying this

> alert(Math.abs(kar))

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use split function

try below code..

var jj= kar.split('-')